# Error Number: 1153, Exrpression Engine 2.7.3

Tags: solspace, mysql, solspace-importer

We're having an issues on "Importer". While we're importing data to our site we encounter [this error](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a33u8ko45). The site is on shared-hosting. Please we need help on this.

UPDATE: Here is the error message:
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1153
Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
Filename: third_party/importer/mod.importer.php
Line Number: 327

Note: I can't post the SQL query because it's too long but the query is trying to UPDATE the "exp_importer_batches" table.

Comment: What version of Importer? It would be good to post the error here in case that link becomes obsolete. Can you increase the value of `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL? That or try importing less data at a time. This error seems to be caused by the limited resources on your hosting.

Comment: We did try to import the data by chunks (10000) rows in each CSV file, still the error persist. Unfortunately we can't change the max_allowed_packet as of now :(

Comment: A google search reveals that error is exactly as it states. Try batches of 1000 and see how that runs. The common fix is to update mysql to accept larger packets.